# Making a Progressbar show progress of a download in a backgroundworker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar, backgroundworker, webclient

I'm coding an application that will download files one at a time, it all works fine so far, but I ran into some problems once I tried to make my progressbar display the progress of the download. I've done it before, but this is the first time I'm doing all of this on a backgroundworker thread. The reason I'm using DownloadFile instead of DownloadFileAsync is because I need it to download the files one at a time, and I found doing it this way was a bit easier.

This is a part of the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        if (!bw.IsBusy)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Patching Completed.");
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        barPatch.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        doPatch();

    }

    private void doPatch()
    {

        for (int C = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText("Client.txt")); C < S; C++)
        {
            this.lblC.InvokeEx(lbl => lblC.Text = Convert.ToString(C + 1));
            wc.DownloadFile(String.Format("http://localhost:1234/Launcher/Patches/{0}.zip", C + 1), String.Format("{0}.zip", C + 1));
            File.WriteAllText("Client.txt", Convert.ToString(C + 1));
        }
    }

    void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wc.DownloadFileAsync` instead of `wc.DownloadFile`

And in `wc_DownloadProgressChanged` use

`bw.ReportProgress(e.BytesReceived / e.TotalBytesToReceive * 100);`

You can visit

[WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And

[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For more help.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to use Async since it attempts to download all of the files at once. I know that it's possible to make a queue, but I just thought that using DownloadFile on a backgroundworker would be less time consuming.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah I tried doing that, but nothing happened. Could it be because the webclient is doing it's work on a different thread, and the `DownloadProgressChanged` only affects that thread and not the UI one?

Comment: I think if you tried to use `DownloadFileAsync` at new thread it will work as `DownloadFile`

Answer (score 0):

A VERY dirty trick but you can get progress of any filesize changing if you do this:

```
        class InfoForDownload
        {
              public string FileName {get; set;}
              public int FileSize {get; set;}
        }

        int fileSizeFromCheck;

        InfoForDownload info = new InfoForDownload() { FileName = "C:\Users\TheUser\OneDrive\Documents\etc\etc\backup.sql", FileSize = THEFILESIZEOFTHEFILEONEXTERNAL };

        BackgroundWorker checkDownload = new BackgroundWorker();
        checkDownload.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        checkDownload.ProgressChanged += checkDownload_ProgressChanged;
        checkDownload.DoWork += checkDownload_DoWork;
        checkDownload.RunWorkerAsync(info);

        void downloadWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
              BackgroundWorker checkDownload = (sender as BackgroundWorker);
              if (e.Argument != null)
              {
                    InfoForDownload info = (sender as InfoForDownload);
                    ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    cmdStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
                    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    cmdStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    cmdStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cmdStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                    while(info.FileSize > fileSizeFromCheck){
                          Process cmdProcess = new Process();
                          cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
                          cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
                          cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
                          cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                          cmdProcess.Start();
                          cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                          cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
                          cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("for %I in (info.FileName) do @echo %~zI");
                          cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                          cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
                          Thread.Sleep(200);
                          Console.WriteLine("The size of the file is " + fileSizeFromCheck + " " + (info.FileSize / fileSizeFromCheck  * 100) + "%");
                          checkDownload.ReportProgress(info.FileSize / fileSizeFromCheck  * 100);
                    }

              }
        }

        void checkDownload_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
              progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
              Console.WriteLine("Output from other process");
              Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
              Int32.TryParse((e.Data / 1024) / 1024, out fileSizeFromCheck);
        }
```

Make the edits to fit your use and a progressbar named progressBar. Voila. Dirty as dirty can be.